# Baking to Filmic or Filmic Log in Blender 2.9?

Tags: baking

I’m trying to bake a texture I relit and as it’s a white texture, the lighting is blowing at places. In photography this is a typical sign of a camera with low dynamic range. I found some articles and tutorials pointing to the Filmic and Filmic Log profiles in Blender and indeed using one of them the image looks correct with no overexposed or blowing areas. But as far as I can see this is just a view setting. How do I bake more dynamic range?

How do I bake to Filmic or Filmic Log?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add a screenshot or blend file.

Answer (score 1):

When you save the baked image check *Save as Render* to apply the render view transformation.

**Update**

The PNG standard is an 8/16-bit integer format.  To preserve HDR information you must use a file format that supports floating point, which means Radiance HDR or OpenEXR in Blender's case.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/media/image_formats.html

Comment: It is better actually to use exr. This bypasses the transforms, allowing the full dynamic range. png, is not useful and saving as  render disallows further manipulation of the image elsewhere should it be desired later.